# How to crimp a ferrules(end sleeve)without a crimper?

Tags: crimp

[image]

Hi.

I know that the best way and the safe method to crimp those uninsulated ferrules is to use the appropriate crimper.
But,since i need to crimp only 3-4 wires,buying a special crimper only for that is not economic.
Which other method can i use in order that the crimp of those uninsulated end sleeve will be good enough?

Thanks.

Comment: Good enough for what? I can only suggest to experiment and see what works for your needs. Try squeezing them with some pliers?

Comment: I meant,good enough to hold the wire strands,gets into the slot with the screw and let the current flows without increase the resistance.

Comment: There will always be an increase in resistance, even with a proper crimper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on experience trying myself: Just get the cheapest ferrule crimp tool you can find.

It will be better than trying to use pliers, which doesn't really make a crimp because it squashes them flat and they can easily open up from that. Flattened ferrules are also very wide and don't fit in screw terminals that would otherwise hold that gauge of wire.

Comment: You can always resell it if you're sure you'll never need it again.

Comment: Or try to find somebody locally who has one you can borrow. You may for example have a nearby "maker space" with either a selection of tools available or at least a number of other people who may have such things...

Comment: Is this the only method?:squash them flat.since this is,indeed,the only thing that i found in the net.I though,maybe,there is something better to do that by using the regular tools?Borrow crimper is impossible and rare here,no one that i know have it.And,as i said,buying even cheap tool for crimping 3 wires doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using these ferrules for a cable that needs to be robust and last, I'd go for the crimper or borrow one. The crimpers have exact dimensions to crimp the cable properly.

That being said, if you only have a few crimps, maybe a terminal crimper might be a close second.

I have bought decent crimpers on ebay for a fraction of the cost of the new one, and I don't need a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider an ordinary crimping tool.  Most everybody has one of those.

[image]

Comment: I am familiar with the crimper in the photo and this type of crimper might be worth to buy,but which dies in that crimper suitable for crimping the uninsulated ferrule?There is the non insulation dies in the middle of the tool,but I don't think that it is for ferrule or maybe it can?

Comment: I was thinking the smallest ( 1.5 ).  But the pliers idea is worth a try.